# Excluding specific files from gradle dependency download

Tags: java, ant, gradle

I am transitioning a java build from ANT to Gradle.  I am attempting to filter what actually gets downloaded from the repository by file name or extension.

For example, the ANT dependency looks like this:

```
<dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate" rev="${hibernate.version}" conf="compile,        runtime->default">
        <exclude ext="zip"/>
</dependency>
```

I have my Gradle set up like so currently but does not seem to be working

```
runtime (group:"org.hibernate", name:"hibernate", version:"${hibernate_version}"){
        exclude (group:"javax.transaction", module:'javadoc')
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please explain the problem in more detail (exact error message, Gradle version, etc.).

Comment: Gradle Version 1.10, and I get an error: Could not download artifact 'javax.transaction:jta:1.1"javadoc.zip'  Artifact 'javax.transaction:jta:1.1"javadoc.zip' not found

Comment: Exact error message? Which repositories do you have declared? I don't think there is an Ivy/Maven module named `javadoc`. By the way, this dependency should probably go on the `compile` configuration.

Comment: Is this coming from Maven Central?

Comment: I am using an Artifactory Repo

Comment: Does it ultimately come from Maven Central? I don't see a `javadoc.zip` artifact for `jta:1.1` there. First you'll have to figure out where `javadoc.zip` is referenced.

Comment: Honestly I am not sure where it is referenced.  I asked around a little bit and have been searching but the best I got was it gets pulled down when it is downloaded.  We are using the Artifactory to manage our Ivy repository. In this transition from Ant to Gradle there are few instances where I need to exclude but extension.

Comment: Ok so I think I may have found where it is referenced.  In the ivy-1.1.xml file in the .gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.transaction\jat\1.1\(random)\ivy-1.1.xml there is    <publications>
        <artifact/>
        <artifact name="javadoc" type="javadoc" ext="zip"/>
    </publications>
</ivy-module>

Comment: And where does that come from? An `ivy.xml` on your Artifactory?

Comment: I believe so.  It is a Generated file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to exclude specific artifacts of an Ivy publication. (`exclude` excludes transitive Ivy modules.) One potential solution is to use the "single artifact" notation (`"org.hibernate:hibernate:${gradleVersion}@jar"`) and handle transitive dependencies yourself. Another solution is to adapt the `ivy.xml` on Artifactory.